# Patterns/Best Practices version of Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, best-practices

I've been thinking about this for some time now. Stack Overflow is great for looking up answers to specific (mostly long tail) questions. Sometimes you find bits and pieces of what you need, and put them all together to form a good solution. There are other times where the top answers have security holes or other major issues, or simply answer the question directly without going into other things the person should consider.

While most projects/websites use the same few patterns for authentication, database connections, commenting system, etc. Developers keep recreating the wheel with every new project.

What I would love to help build is a knowledge base that's up to date, with different [patterns/best practices/full examples] to problems using the Stack Exchange system. Each solution would be up/down voted, the same as an answer is now for a question. Users could easily browse all the different patterns prior to starting their project and learn the most recommended solutions (Side benefit of preventing the same questions being asked about simple things on Stack Overflow). The same problem/question can have multiple version for different languages/platforms/technologies. For example the web authentication pattern would have a version for ASP.NET, MVC, PHP, Ruby, etc. using a Database, Active Directory, OpenID, etc.

Also just having a way to see what solutions different projects have implemented would be great. How does the login/authentication system of Stack Overflow differ from Facebook, Google, Digg, Reddit, etc? Which solution has what advantages?

I've thought about starting a site with this idea, but with a full time job and a startup that takes up the rest of my time, I don't have the capacity right now. Because this fits in well with Stack Overflow, I figured this is a good place to get the idea out there.

Is there anything that exists like this already? Does anyone else want this resource to be created?

Comment: As discussed below, the proper place to discuss and propose ideas for new sites is [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). As such, I am going to close this as off topic for *this* forum.

Answer (score 3):

The place to start new sites is [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but there is already a site that says it for best practices, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

From their FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are
>   working on for peer review. If you are looking for specific feedback
>   about…
>
> ```
> Code correctness
> Best practices and design pattern usage in your code
> Application UI
> Security issues in a code snippet, etc.
> The performance of your code
> ```
>
> and your question is not about …
>
> ```
> Tools, best practices, improving, or conducting code reviews
> Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
> ```
>
> … then you are in the right place!

Comment: Lance, thanks, I'm moved my idea to Area 51. The Code Review site is not the same thing I was suggesting.